# How to add a header tag in Drupal 6?

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

I need to add a tag to the header. I open page.tpl.php and I see this line:

```
<?php print $head; ?>
```

I assume I should write that tag somewhere else. What is the proper way of adding it? Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`drupal_set_html_head()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--common.inc/function/drupal_set_html_head/6) to add a tag into the head section of the html

For example, `drupal_set_html_head()` can optionally be used in [`template_preprocess_page()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--theme.inc/function/template_preprocess_page/6) as described [here](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--common.inc/function/drupal_set_html_head/6#comment-4614)

Answer (score 2):

If you're simply creating your own site, that's probably around the right place to do it, in page.tpl.php - somewhere between `<head>` and `</head>`.  The template is as straightforward as it looks in that spot.

`drupal_set_html_head()` is what you'd want to use if you are writing a Drupal module (so people who use your module get the appropriate header, no matter what theme they're using).